# How to add rscala dependency in build.gradle

Tags: scala, build.gradle

I would like to embed R in a Scala application, so how should I specify the dependency in the *build.gradle* file.

I found the following for sbt project.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.ddahl" %% "rscala" % "2.2.2"
```

Could someone please help me to specify the same in Gradle?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the dependency to your build definition like follows:

```
compile group: 'org.ddahl', name: 'rscala_2.11', version: '2.2.2'
```

As you may notice, while in SBT by using the `%%` operator you can omit the Scala version for which the library has been compiled, in Gradle (just like Maven) you have to state it explicitly, thus the dependency definition can change according to the Scala version you are using:

```
compile group: 'org.ddahl', name: 'rscala_2.10', version: '2.2.2'
compile group: 'org.ddahl', name: 'rscala_2.11', version: '2.2.2'
compile group: 'org.ddahl', name: 'rscala_2.12', version: '2.2.2'
```

If you want to know more about the binary compatibility policy across Scala versions [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/binary-compatibility-of-scala-releases.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton @stefanobaghino ,that worked like a charm :)

Comment: @user1105412 Awesome, feel free to upvote the answer and accept it if you have found it useful. :-)